Find the limit of a sequence of functions : What did I miss?
The question was to find the limit of a sequence of functions
$$f_{n}(x) = n^{4}x^{4}\sin\left (  \frac{x}{n^{2}+n} \right )$$
and to find for which numbers the sequence converges.
I solved it using l'Hospital's rule by re-writing it as
$$ f_{n}(x) =\frac{\sin\left (  \frac{x}{n^{2}+n} \right )}{\frac{1}{n^{4}x^{4}}} $$
I ended up with
$$\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{n^{2}+n})x^{5}(2n+1)n^{5}}{4(n^{2}+n)^{2}}$$
For $n$ going to infinity, this will be either

infinity for $x>0$
-infinity for $x<0$
or $0$ for $x=0$

My problem is that I found this exact problem in one of my textbooks and allegedly the result is supposed to be $x^{5}$ and the sequence of functions should be converging for every real number $x$.
I can't figure out how in the world they got the result. The results of my other set of problems match the results in the book.
Where did I go wrong in my computations?

Are you sure of the $n^4$ ? basically if $x$ fixed then $f_n(x)\sim n^2x^5$, so I would have put $n^2$ instead of $n^4$.

The given answer is incorrect.  Either you have written down the problem incorrectly or the textbook is wrong.

@JairTaylor I've even asked my parents to check if I wrote jtdown right and I really did. I've solved a few more problems and I found out that some other solutions are wrong too. I checked by plugging in various values for x and looking at the graph of the function.

@zwim I'm 100% sure.

To be clear, by "the given answer" I meant the textbook answer. Your answer is correct and the textbook is wrong, or else there was a transcription error in copying the question from the book to here.
